# Macbook pro - thick vertical bar appeared on my screen

Tags: laptop, display, macbook-pro

the last few days, a vertical bar (about 300 pixels wide) has been plaguing my macbook pro screen. sometimes it's solid white, sometimes it flickers in colors, sometimes it disappears!
 i'm pretty sure it's not a software issue because it's permanently there even right after startup....anybody have any idea what could be going on here ?

Answer (score 4):

that sounds like a broken display to me. I don´t know Mac that well (windows user...) but are you able to test the grafics with an external monitor? I am pretty sure, this is caused by a broken lcd display. Does it look like the picture below? If so, it definitely is a broken display.

[image: http://img.skitch.com/20100108-q7hrgc4btr2kgxju6bdwgweepb.jpg]

Image source: http://ask.metafilter.com/tags/screen

Comment: yes looks exactly like that :) i don't have the proper cables to check external display but will do that today

Answer (score 0):

The problem magically went away, I was away for a few days and now back and it's gone. Very strange. I will still take it to get checked.

Comment: It could've simply been a loose connection somewhere. Either way, not a good sign :(

Comment: If you're still in warranty, better go to apple store and show them that picture above posted by Diskilla. Better do that while in warranty than outside warranty

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you, but the problem seems to be temperature-related for me.

My macbook (5,1) has been having the same flicker issue for a year or so now. I've been having my furnace repaired this week, so my house has been getting really cold at night. When I woke up this morning, my macbook didn't flicker anymore.

After the computer warmed up, the flickering came back. Then, I tried sticking it in front of a desk fan. Lo and behold, the screen no longer flickers. I know it isn't an ideal solution, but it fixes the problem as long as you have a desk fan on hand.